# Compile the Fortran program in Windows using gfortran

Tags: linux, fortran, window, gfortran

I have a Fortran program(.f) that I have written in Ubuntu Linux. I compiled the written Fortran program in Linux by using the below command and it it successfully executed.

```
gfortran -o program  program.f
```

Now I want to execute the same Fortran program in Windows 10 Can it be executed in window system? If so please suggest me a way to do it.

I tried     `gfortran -o program  program.f`  in Windows command window,but it fails.

Comment: If your command fails, you really have to say what exactly happens. Any error messages? If yes, show them.

Answer (score 1):

To compile Fortran code for Windows you need a Fortran compiler for Windows.  Microsoft neither provides a built-in one nor offers one for sale.  Third-party compilers are available, including `gfortran`, but you'll need to install one yourself.  If you want to use `gfortran` in particular, or if you like it simply because you don't have to spend money to get it, then I would recommend obtaining it as part of [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php).  Alternatives are available from [multiple vendors](https://fortran-lang.org/compilers/), some free of charge, but most for sale.

Note also that Windows expects executables to be named with an `.exe` extenstion, so you would want to use a variation on gfortran your compilation command:

```
gfortran -o program.exe  program.f
```

Comment: how can i get directly the binary file of mingw-64 to install in window

Comment: I already linked to the mingw-w64 site, @seist.  There are downloads and documentation there.

Comment: while i am doing the same i am getting error collect2.exe:error: id returned 1 exit status

Comment: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../.......undefined reference to 'engplt','pen',/...

Comment: can you please suggest a solution for the same @John Bollinger

Comment: @seist, that would be an entirely different question.  I would suggest posing it as one if you cannot find an existing answer to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use gfortran on Windows, I suggest you install [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/), which has a bash terminal, and a package manager that can install gcc and gfortran, as well as lapack and many other libraries.

There is also a separate distribution of [mingw-w64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/) that can be installed without MSYS2, but I don't recommend it, as the last files there have gcc-8.1.0, from 2018 (apart from a recent build by Ray Linn that includes the Ada, but not the Fortran compiler).

Another compiler that is now free is Intel Fortran : you have to install [Microsoft Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/en/vs/community/), Intel oneAPI Base Toolkit and  Intel oneAPI HPC Toolkit. More information [here](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/all-toolkits.html). Available on Linux, macOS and Windows (of course, Visual Studio is needed only on Windows). Intel oneAPI is at least partly [open source](https://github.com/oneapi-src), not sure about the Fortran compiler.

MSYS2 is a *much* smaller package (in terms of disk pace needed), and is used by several other free projects: [R](https://cran.r-project.org/) (Rtools), [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) and [Strawberry Perl](https://strawberryperl.com/) all include parts of it, including the gcc compilers.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023, the following steps are tested successfully on a Windows 11 PC.

1. [http://www.equation.com](http://www.equation.com/servlet/equation.cmd?fa=fortran), provides 32 and 64-bit x86 executables
   for GCC version 12.1 which includes GNU Fortran, C and C++. Make a note of where it is installing the gcc. This will be useful in step 3.
2. Once installed, restart your PC.
3. Add `gcc/bin` folder which contains the gcc and gfortran executables to the PATH variable in your environment variable settings
4. `gfortran program.f -o program.exe`